# Android appending a timestamp to a file

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

It's been a long and annoying day and I had code working which would create and write to a file and also append a date and time to the end of it. But I must have changed something and for the life of me I can't see what I have done wrong.

If someone could just point out the simple mistake I have made, that would be great.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy / hh-mm-ss");
Date curDate = new Date();
String stringDate = sdf.format(curDate);
String resultLogFile = "resultsFile " + stringDate;
File resultsFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + resultLogFile);
if (!resultsFile.exists())
{
    try
    {
        resultsFile.createNewFile();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
try
{
    BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(resultsFile, true));
    buf.append(writeToFileString);
    buf.newLine();
    buf.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you are trying to create a file with a filename like **"/mnt/sdcard/resultsFile 22-09-2012 / 11-22-33"**. This is most likely an invalid file name. Does the `createNewFile()` call succeed? Also, you are appending `writeToFileString` to the file, but that variable isn't declared or set in the code you posted, so I've no idea what that is.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is the slash in your DateFormat string or do you try to create a folder for the day and a file for hh-mm-ss? In that case you should get rid of the spaces around the slash and call `resultsFile.mkdirs()` before `resultsFile.createNewFile()` to make sure that the directory `resultsFile dd-MM-yyyy` exists. But I'm pretty sure you do not want directories, so just replace the slash in the DateFormat with something else.